# "Could not unwrap Operation" with Apache CXF

Tags: xml, apache, cxf

I'm trying to deploy a webservice using cxf.

I use the following code to declare my endPoint

```
<jaxws:endpoint
xmlns:wsdl="com_documentation_service_standardfeatures_application_webservices_uc51_webserviceServer_WebServiceSearch"  
 id="webServiceSearchEndpoint"
    implementor="#com.documentation.service.standardfeatures.application.webservices.uc51_webserviceServer.WebServiceSearch"
    wsdlLocation="classpath:resources/schemas/wsdl/com_documentation_service_standardfeatures_application_webservices_uc51_webserviceServer_WebServiceSearch.wsdl"
    endpointName="wsdl:WebServiceSearchPort"
    serviceName="wsdl:com_documentation_service_standardfeatures_application_webservices_uc51_webserviceServer_WebServiceSearch"
    address="http://localhost:8888/service2"
    />
```

And my wsdl looks like that

```
[...]
<wsdl:types>
<schema targetNamespace="com_documentation_service_standardfeatures_application_webservices_uc51_webserviceServer_WebServiceSearch_types" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:team51="com_documentation_business_standardfeatures_application_webservices_uc51_webserviceClient_entities_Team51"    >
    <import namespace="com_documentation_business_standardfeatures_application_webservices_uc51_webserviceClient_entities_Team51" schemaLocation="classpath:resources/schemas/xsd/com_documentation_business_standardfeatures_application_webservices_uc51_webserviceClient_entities_Team51.xsd"/>
    <element name="team51" type="team51:team51"/>
    <element name="anyType" type="xsd:anyType"/>
    <element name="string" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element name="integer" type="xsd:integer"/>
    <element name="float" type="xsd:float"/>
    <element name="long" type="xsd:long"/>
    <element name="dateTime" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
    <element name="boolean" type="xsd:boolean"/>        
    <element name="collection" type="types:collectionType"/>        
    <complexType name="collectionType">
        <sequence>
            <element type="xsd:anyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="element"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>  
</schema>
</wsdl:types>

  <wsdl:message name="team51FindByID">
    <wsdl:part name="id" element="types:long"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="team51FindByIDResponse">
       <wsdl:part name="return" element="types:team51"/>
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:portType name="WebServiceSearch">  
   <wsdl:operation name="team51FindByID">
     <wsdl:input name="team51FindByID" message="team51FindByID">
   </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output name="team51FindByIDResponse" message="team51FindByIDResponse">
   </wsdl:output>
   </wsdl:operation>    
 </wsdl:portType>  
[...]
```

When running tomcat server, the following message always appears.

```
 ATTENTION: Could not unwrap Operation {documentation_service_standardfeatures_application_webservices_uc51_webserviceServer_WebServiceSearch}team51FindByID to match method "public abstract Type1 team51FindByID(java.lang.Long)"

 org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl initDestination
```

What's wrong with my configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Run the wsdl2java on that wsdl and make sure the method signatures match what is generated.   It looks like you don't have the @SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE) annotation and the return type on that mehod is wrong.  (looks like it should be a Team51, not a Type1)

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I just ran wsdl2java but the tool automaticaly added the  **SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE** annotation.
I would prefer to use **SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.Wrapped** mode so that i could declare multiple operations in my webservice. 
Maybe something is missing in my configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

The namespace where you define the Operation is not correct. Error is precisely uncovering on what class the namespace is not correct, so it can not find it and can not unwrap.

Fixing the namespace should enable you proper WSDL creation.